# how to check if a model is tagged by a specific tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, relationship

I have model Entity and related model Tag. The later serves as tags, so the relation is serviced by a pivot table

I guess it is quite easy, but I am lost.

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'entity_tags', 'entity_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Now, in my view I can list all tags:
They are defined

```
{!! 
    join(
        ', ',
        array_map(
            function($o) {
                return link_to_route('entities.profile',
                $o->name,
                [$o->id],
                ['class' => 'ui blue tag button']
            );
        }, 
        $object->tags->all())
    )
!!}
```

My question:

how in BLADE I can check if the Entity object has a specific capacity?

in my controller SHOW method I get one single Entity:

```
$object = Entity::find(34);
```

and then i wish to do sth if  the entity is tagged by a certain tag

```
@if($object->capacities .... has tag=  3
 // do things here
@endif
```

Comment: $object->tags->all() what is $object here is it $o ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if an Entity has a certain tag like this:

```
@if($entity->tags()->where('id', 3)->exists()) //.... has tag=  3
   // do things here
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a public method to your Entity class wich would let you check for an existing tag on this entity :

```
<?php
public function hasTag($tagToMatch)
{
   foreach ($this->tags as $tag)
   {
      if ($tag->id == $tagToMatch)
         return (true);
   }
   return (false);
}
```

This would allow you to use the following code in your views :

```
@if ($entity->hasTag(3))
   Do something
@endif
```